# Apt-get update error on ubuntu 16.04 by using Ansible playbook

Tags: docker, ansible, ubuntu-16.04

I have written ansible playbook for installing the docker on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
While running the ansible playbook, I am getting apt-get update error

I have tried running the attached playbook code.

```yaml
      - hosts: docker
        become: yes
        become_user: root
        tasks:
           - name: apt-get update
             shell: apt-get update -y
           - name: Install packages to allow apt to use a repository   overHTTPS
             shell: sudo apt-get install -y \
                    apt-transport-https -y \
                    ca-certificates \
                    curl \
                    gnupg-agent \
                    software-properties-common
           - name: Add Docker’s official GPG key
             shell: curl -fsSL    https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
           - name: Use the following command to set up the stable repository
             shell: add-apt-repository \
                    "deb [arch=amd64]   https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu\
                    $(lsb_release -cs) \
                    stable"
           - name: apt update
             shell: apt-get update -y
           - name: Installing the docker 17.03.0
             shell: apt-get install docker-ce=18.06.1~ce-3-0~ubuntu -y
```

Before installing the docker, I try to update the ubuntu server, but I am getting below error

```
          TASK [apt update]      **************************************************************
         fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "apt-         get update -y", "delta": "0:00:12.338257",
         "end": "2019-04-02 11:58:13.377956", "failed": true, "rc":   100, "start": "2019-04-02 11:58:01.039699",
          "stderr": "W: The repository   'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu\\ xenial Release' does not    have
          a Release file.\nE: Failed to fetch    https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu\\/dists/xenial/\\/binary-
         amd64/Packages  404  Not Found\nE: Some index files failed to   download. They have been ignored, or old 
         ones used instead.", "stdout": "Hit:1 http://us-  east1.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease\nH
         it:2 http://us-east1.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial- updates InRelease\nHit:3 http://us-east1.gce.
         archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease\nHit:4   http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial 
         InRelease\nHit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ansible/ansible/ubuntu xenial InRelease\nHit:6   http://securit
         y.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease\nIgn:7   https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu\\ xenial 
         InRelease\nIgn:8 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu\\   xenial Release\nIgn:9 https://download.dock
        er.com/linux/ubuntu\\ xenial/\\ amd64 Packages\nIgn:10 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu\\ xenia
        l/\\ all Packages\nIgn:11   https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu\\ xenial/\\ Translation-  en_US\nIgn:1
        2 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu\\ xenial/\\   Translation-en\nIgn:13 https://download.docker.c
        om/linux/ubuntu\\ xenial/stable amd64 Packages\nIgn:14 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu\\ xenia
        l/stable all Packages\nIgn:15   https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu\\ xenial/stable Translation-  en_U
         S\nIgn:16 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu\\   xenial/stable Translation-en\nIgn:9 https://downlo
         ad.docker.com/linux/ubuntu\\ xenial/\\ amd64 Packages\nIgn:10    https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu\
         \ xenial/\\ all Packages\nIgn:11   https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu\\ xenial/\\ Translation-en_US
          \nIgn:12 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu\\ xenial/\\     Translation-en\nIgn:13 https://download.d
         ocker.com/linux/ubuntu\\ xenial/stable amd64 Packages\nIgn:14   https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu\
         \ xenial/stable all Packages\nIgn:15     https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu\\ xenial/stable Translati
        on-en_US\nIgn:16 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu\\    xenial/stable Translation-en\nIgn:9 https:/
        /download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu\\ xenial/\\ amd64      Packages\nIgn:10 https://download.docker.com/linux/
        ubuntu\\ xenial/\\ all Packages\nIgn:11    https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu\\ xenial/\\ Translatio
         n-en_US\nIgn:12 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu\\  xenial/\\ Translation-en\nIgn:13 https://dow
         nload.docker.com/linux/ubuntu\\ xenial/stable amd64    Packages\nIgn:14 https://download.docker.com/linux/
       ubuntu\\ xenial/stable all Packages\nIgn:15 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu\\ xenial/stable Tr
        anslation-en_US\nIgn:16 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu\\ xenial/stable Translation-en\nIgn:9 
       https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu\\ xenial/\\ amd64 Packages\nIgn:10 https://download.docker.com
      /linux/ubuntu\\ xenial/\\ all Packages\nIgn:11  https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu\\ xenial/\\ Tra
      nslation-en_US\nIgn:12 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu\\ xenial/\\ Translation-en\nIgn:13 http
        s://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu\\ xenial/stable amd64  Packages\nIgn:14 https://download.docker.com
     /linux/ubuntu\\ xenial/stable all Packages\nIgn:15
```

Comment: The shell command in `add-apt-repository` to add the docker repo looks a bit broken. Can you simplify that line (remove the trailing backslashes, put everything in one long line) and try again. You could also print a debug message with the command that is run, to ensure it's correct.

Comment: @Augusto, i removed trailing backslashes and put everything in one long line, but i getting same error.

Answer (score 6):

You have many mistakes in your shell commands:

- 2 `-y` in your `apt-get install` command
- a mix of `\` and `"` in your shell commands

But more importantly, you should avoid to use `shell` module when a module that do the job exists, and in your case, you can use 3 modules:

- [apt](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/apt_module.html)
- [apt_key](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/apt_key_module.html)
- [apt_repository](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/apt_repository_module.html)

Something like should work:

```
- hosts: docker
  become: yes

  tasks:

    - name: Update repositories cache and install packages
      apt:
        name: apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg-agent software-properties-common
        update_cache: yes

    - name: Add Docker PGP key
      apt_key:
        url: https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg
        state: present

    - name: Add docker apt repository
      apt_repository:
        repo: "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu ... stable"
        state: present

    - name: Update repositories cache and install packages
      apt:
        name: docker-ce
        update_cache: yes
```

Comment: I have followed your suggestions. While running the playbook, again i getting same apt-get error-->fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to update apt cache: E:The repository 'https://download.
docker.com/linux/ubuntu\\ bionic Release' does not have a Release file., W:Updating from such a repository can't be done 
securely, and is therefore disabled by default., W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configurati
on details., E:The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release Release' does not have a Release file."}

Comment: FYI.                                                                                                                                  - name: update
      apt:
         update_cache: yes
    - name: Update repositories cache and install packages
      apt:
        name: docker-ce=18.06.1~ce~3-0~ubuntu
        state: present

Comment: @CHBHARATHKUMAR Sounds like maybe the repository config is faulty or the repository is broken. Does the same thing work for you if you run the non-ansible commands manually?